# Adding multiple function calls to a case of in delphi?

Tags: delphi

```
  case i of
         0..99  :   Function-call('bobo') ;
         100..209 : function-smell('Hobo');
         210..300 : function-yikes('argh');
       end;
```

But what if I wanted 210..300 to call both function yikes and function smell?  Can't figure out how thanks.

Comment: Just a side note: if you use "else" in your case, then you can have multiple statements AFTER else, without the need to write a begin/end.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just add a begin end block:

```
case i of
  0..99    : function-call('bobo') ;
  100..209 : function-smell('Hobo');
  210..300 : begin
    function-yikes('argh');
    function-smell('Hobo');
  end;
end;
```